# How to check if variable is empty

Tags: linux, bash, script

I've made a script to execute rsync only when $VAR (part of a file path) has some content and in case it's empty the script will stop and return error 1. This is the command:

```
test -n $VAR && rsync -rHptgoz --delete "$ORIGEN$VAR/" "$DESTI" || exit 1
```

So if before that command I add `VAR=''` the script should exit but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). `test -n` is very different than `test -n ''`.

Comment: You might want to read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).